# C# - remove part of listbox items

Tags: c#

I have a `ListBox` which has a collection of files from a directory and I need to remove the extension from them. They will all be m4a format so that should make it a bit easier. However I have searched and cannot find a solution.

I am very new to programming and would appreciate some help. If I could request an example I would really appreciate it and could you please use `lstSong` instead of a placeholder because I get confused as to whats a placeholder and not in examples.

As requested the code that writes to it:

```
string[] songspaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(librarypath + "/" + albumpath + "/" + songpath);

List<string> listsongs = new List<string>();

foreach (var f in songspaths)
{
   string songs = f.Split('\\').Last();
   lstSong.Items.Add(songs);
}
```

I am unsure exactly how this code works. I understand most of it but it was written by a friend to help me. Which is why i was going to do it afterwards.
Thanks again.

Comment: I'd say do this in the viewmodel and expose a simple bindable collection, another option is a converter.

Comment: How do you bind this collection to your listbox? Post come code. Is it even WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Do you have a 'collection of files' or a 'collection of filenames'? Are you trying to remove the last four characters of each filename?

Comment: Yeah basically i need to get rid of the last four characters. It is a windows form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding from your comment you only need the filename of the files, without the path or the extension.
For that you can use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

```
string[] songspaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(librarypath + "/" + albumpath + "/" + songpath); // Get all the files from the specified directory

List<string> listsongs = new List<string>();

foreach (var f in songspaths)
{
   lstSong.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)); // Store the filename without path or extension in the list
}
```

And to explain the code your friend has wrote:

```
string songs = f.Split('\\').Last();
```

The [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method diviedes the string into an array of substrings delimited by the given character.
In this case it's an ([escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)) backslash.
The `.Last()` returns the last element of the array.

Comment: That worked perfectly and now that part of my program works as it should. Thanks heaps for your help.